# SQLite with EntityFramework Exception: Cannot open database requested by the login

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sqlite

App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />

    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQLiteConnection" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\wzz\source\repos\PutixinEditor\PutixinEditor\db.sqlite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

my dbContext:

```
    class PutixinDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public PutixinDbContext() : base("SQLiteConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<PutixinDbContext>(null);

        }

        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }

    }
```

But when I context.SaveChanges(), error throw:

```
SqlException: Cannot open database "SQLiteConnection" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-BR8U8NG\wzz'.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 0):

Error: `"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MyComputer\myUser'."`

The error is very misleading because in your case, it will happen even if the the user has full permissions to write to the file and directory in question, in your case directory C:\Users\wzz\source\repos\PutixinEditor\PutixinEditor\ and file C:\Users\wzz\source\repos\PutixinEditor\PutixinEditor\db.sqlite.

The name of the string parameter passed to the DBContext constructor is "nameOrConnectionString". You are not passing a connection string, but instead your provider name. You have no such connection string.

As per Microsofts documentation, since no such connection string is found, the name is passed to the DefaultConnectionFactory, which wants to connect to a MsSQL or SqlExpress database. This is probably where the "Login failed" message comes from.

However,there is no ConnectionFactory class in System.Data.Sqlite.EF6 (v4.0.30319) which you could use instead.

Here is what will work: Create and name a separate connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SQLiteConnection" connectionString="data source=C:\Users\wzz\source\repos\PutixinEditor\PutixinEditor\db.sqlite;foreign keys=true" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You also have to configure the corresponding ProviderFactory, or else you'll get an error about not finding the requested provider 
(With the friendly message "The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded.").

The provider factory you need is System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory (from the System.Data.SQLite assembly).

```
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Now your DbContext should work.

I got the same error when I misspelled the name of the connection string in the constructor of the DbContext. It was very confusing because there was absolutely nothing wrong with the permissions of the sqlite file.